# React JS state doesn't update on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My showroom component is as follows :

```
export default class Showrooms extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        blockView: true
    };
}

handleChangeView(view){
    console.log(view);
    this.setState({blockView: view});
}

render(){
    const language = this.props.language;
    return (
        <div className="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <div className="lists">
                <div className="listsTitle">{language.portal.introPageTitle}</div>

                <ViewBar handleChangeView={this.handleChangeView.bind(this)}/>

                <div className="allLists">
                    <div className="view">

                        {this.props.allLists.map( (list, i) =>  <View key={i} list={list} language={language} blockView={this.state.blockView}/>)}

                        <div className="clearfix"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="clearfix"/>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

and my viewBar component is as follows :

```
export default class ViewBar extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        blockView: true
    };
}

setBlockView(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({blockView: true}, this.props.handleChangeView(this.state.blockView));
}

setListView(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({blockView: false}, this.props.handleChangeView(this.state.blockView));
}


render(){
    let blockViewAddBorder = this.state.blockView ? "activeView" : "";
    let listViewAddBorder = !this.state.blockView ? "activeView" : "";
    return (
        <div className="viewBar">
            <Link to="" onClick={this.setListView.bind(this)} className={`listViewIcon ${listViewAddBorder}`}>
                <FontAwesome name="list" className="portalFaIcon"/>
            </Link>
            <Link to="" onClick={this.setBlockView.bind(this)} className={blockViewAddBorder}>
                <FontAwesome name="th-large" className="portalFaIcon"/>
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

In viewBar component I have two onClick functions where I update the state and the I call an function from showroom component to update the state.

Depending on that state I change the way how I display the content.

But the problem is, when the function setListView is called first time, the state doesn't change to false. When I second time call setListView then it sets the state to false.

`this.props.handleChangeView` function is an callback function, and it should be called after the state is updated.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second argument in [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) should be `function`

```
this.setState({ blockView: true }, () => {
   this.props.handleChangeView(this.state.blockView);
})
```

in your example, you pass result to `setState` from `handleChangeView`

```
this.setState({
  blockView: true
}, this.props.handleChangeView(this.state.blockView));
```

`handleChangeView` returns nothing, it means that you pass to `setState` undefined

```
this.setState({
  blockView: true
}, undefined);
```

so you don't call `handleChangeView` after `setState`